# Sumifs(): Limiting the sum_range and criteria_range as to optimize calculation speed when data is sorted.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a sorted data set that's about 50,000 rows long with data that looks like the following:

[image]

In it I have about 3 columns similar to the total column shown here that performs a pretty simple sumifs() calculation.  The problem is that all three happen at the same time and all three look at sum/criteria ranges that are 50,000 cells long and the net result is a really slow calculating workbook.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way to speed up calculation by limit the criteria ranges to a more optimized range that leverages the fact that the data is sorted and so we only ever need the range immediately above and below a given cell.

Thanks

Comment: To how many cells are your current formulas copied? What do you mean by "only ever need the range immediately above and below a given cell."? Why? What is the formula actually calculating? Why have you given an example with an upper row reference of 14 only? And why are the references in that formula all relative, rather than absolute? For example, if that formula is copied down one cell, which I assume it is intended to be, the ranges being referenced will become B3:B15, etc. I assume that's known and intentional?

Comment: @XORLX I'm trying to get the total dollars associated with a given ID summed next to the first observation. The formula is in 3 columns and is copied through 50,000 rows in each column. The actual data starts on line 101 and the relative reference is really something like B51:B151. The reason is that since this data is sorted by id# and since no id# is likely to have more than 20 or so observations, then there isn't a need for us to search from B101:B50000, but only the range from id# (n-1, n+1) (this is what I meant by only needing the immediate range above and below).

Comment: But haven't you effectively answered your own question there, i.e. you set a relative reference such that it is always of the form B(n-50):B(n+50)?

Comment: Knowing what I need to do is not the same as knowing how to do it. But I think you're aware of that.

Comment: No, really. What was wrong with, for example, your reference of  B51:B151?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were being difficult. Yeah, that does work, but the mode for # of observations per id is probably something like 3, so it's overkill for most of my ID#'s. If it's the case that the formula, as written, shouldn't take too much time to execute, then it's no big deal (I don't really know whether that's the case or not), since what I'm really looking for is to stop my workbook from taking a minute to calculate each time I make a change to one of the dynamic variables.

Comment: And you've run tests to verify that it is these precise formulas which are the issue, not any others within your workbook?

Comment: I just ran a quick test. In a new, blank workbook, I entered random data into the range A1:C50000. I then entered the formula =SUMIFS(B1:B101,A1:A101,A51,C1:C101,C51) into cell E51, i.e. one which references a range of 101 cells, comprising the fifty rows prior to and after that containing the formula itself and the single row containing the formula itself. I then copied this formula down to row 50000. I also duplicated these 50000 formulas in the range F51:G50000 to mimic the set-up you describe. Hence a total of just short of 150000 formulas. A full calculation took less than a second.

Comment: I'm really new to Excel, so I'm not sure what a good test would be, however, I noted that deleting the three columns from my workbook has the property of taking calculation speed to 1 second vs 1 minute, so from this I surmised they were probably the best place to start optimizing.

Comment: Okay.  If that's the case I need to think about where the real problem is. The workbook has become more of a database than it should be (50MB), so it's probably time to convince the powers that be that we need to be doing most of the hard work in SAS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30731/discussion-between-xor-lx-and-acemanhattan).

Comment: @Acemanhattan, since you are using `SUMIFS` which already filter rows to `SUM` then after if you need to optimize the exercise you may thing for VBA macro, to apply formula to range at a time.